# Jquery Mobile: Dynamically change the text of the header of a collapsible div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, collapsable

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="e" id="collapsePlace">
    <h3>Place:</h3>
    <!--things...-->
</div>
```

How can I dynamically change the text of the `<h3>` header ('Place:') in the collapsible div?

I tried:

```
$('#collapsePlace').children('h3').text('new text');
```

And it changes the text - but **loses all of the styling!**

Comment: I asked a similar question and I think the answer I was provided is better:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978102/jquery-mobile-change-the-header-of-a-listview/38980002#38980002

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual HTML structure of a collapsible in jQuery Mobile 1.0RC2 is the following (after the framework has made its pass on the HTML):

```
<div id="collapsePlace" data-content-theme="e" data-role="collapsible" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-collapsed">
    <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
        <a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom ui-btn-up-c" href="#" data-theme="c">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom">
                <span class="ui-btn-text">Place:
                    <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
                </span>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus ui-icon-shadow"></span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </h3>
    <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-e ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
        <!--things...-->
    </div>
</div>
```

The nested `<span>` element within the `<span class="ui-btn-text">` element makes this a little tricky. If you want to preserve the structure of the `<span class="ui-btn-text">` element you will need to save the nested `<span>` element, overwrite it, and then replace it:

```
//run code on document.ready
$(function () {
    var num = 1;
    //add click handler to link to increment the collapsible's header each click
    $('a').bind('click', function () {
        //cache the `<span class="ui-btn-text">` element and its child
        var $btn_text  = $('#collapsePlace').find('.ui-btn-text'),
            $btn_child = $btn_text.find('.ui-collapsible-heading-status');
        //overwrite the header text, then append its child to restore the previous structure
        $btn_text.text('New String (' + num++ + ')').append($btn_child);
    });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the above solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/4DAfn/2/

Answer (score 6):

In 1.3.2, the following seem to work:

```
<div id="MyID" data-role="collapsible" >    
    <h3><span id="MyHeaderID">My Header</span></h3>    
    <!-- My Content --> 
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#MyID h3 #MyHeaderID").text("Your New Header");
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Was searching for this. Great!

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be

```
$('#collapsePlace .ui-btn-text').text("hello ");
```

Check out the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/AQZQs/1/

Comment: That will remove the HTML from the `.ui-btn-text` element shown in the question's HTML.

Comment: for later jQuery mobile versions (tested with v 1.4.3), replace ".ui-btn-text" with ".ui-collapsible-heading-toggle"

Answer (score 0):

An easy option is to give the h3 a custom id/class, for example:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="e" id="collapsePlace">
    <h3 id='h3Text'>Place:</h3>
    <!--things...-->
</div>
```

That way you only will need to do:

```
$('#collapsePlace #h3Text').text('new text');
```

Comment: I don't know whether it worked for previous version of JQM but it doesn't work for 1.2.0

Comment: as you can see in this fiddle, style are getting removed though the text changes. http://jsfiddle.net/AQZQs/