# jQuery mobile: Dynamically updating collapsible heading causes loss of styling

Tags: jquery-mobile

After dynamically updating a header tags text for an existing collapsible element, the styling disappears, even though im calling .collapsible({refresh: true}) after updating.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RAxn5/ (click the 'Break it' link to see what i mean).

HTML:

```
<div id="set" data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="set1" data-collapsed="false">
        <h2 class="section_title">Section 1</h2>
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#"><h3>item 1</h3></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><h3>item 2</h3></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><h3>item 3</h3></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="break">Break it</a>
```

JS:

```
$('#break').click(function() {
    $('#set1 h2.section_title').text('Now my style is gone!');
    $('#set1').collapsible({refresh: true});
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should help you: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857218/jquery-mobile-dynamically-change-the-text-of-the-header-of-a-collapsible-div

The issue is caused by the additional elements that jQuery mobile adds.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response mate, you lead me on the right track but it was ultimately Omars answer that i ended up using. I really wish i could select both answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to `span.ui-btn-text` not to `h2`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/RAxn5/15/)**

```
$('#set1 span.ui-btn-text').text('Now my style is gone!');
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution (although a bit hacky) is to find the span that the button sets up and change that rather than the parent id.

```
$('#set1 h2.section_title').find('.ui-btn-text').text('Now my style is gone!');
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9XCD/) for it.

Comment: Yeah that's the main thing to me - it feels very hackish and i would have thought there'd be some refresh event/jquery mobile function to call - i've not been able to find anything.

Comment: It doesn't seem like they have any good options for this at the moment. It would make sense that they should include the section title into the refresh.